# Swagger node express how to Splitting specification file?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

**Can I split my API over multiple YAML files?**

I'm using YAML format to document an API. Is it possible to split the documentation over multiple YAML e.g. I'd like to have something like this:

- parameters_common.yaml - Parameters that are common to a number of
  API's
- parameters_customers.yaml - Parameters that are specific to the
- Customers API swagger.yaml - Customers API (this includes previous
  two yaml files)

  ```
  swagger: '2.0'
  parameters: 
    $ref: parameters_common.yaml
  paths: 
   ...
  ```

  parameters_common.yaml

  ```
  - name: param_one
   ...
  - name: param_two
   ...
  ```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var middleware = require('swagger-express-middleware');
var SwaggerUI = require('swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-ui');
var app = require('express')();
module.exports = app; // for testing

var config = {
  appRoot: __dirname, // required config,  
  swaggerFile: 'api/swagger/swagger.yaml', // which swagger file
};

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

    app.use(SwaggerUI(swaggerExpress.runner.swagger, {
        swaggerUi: '/docs', // Swagger UI URL
        //apiDocs: '/api/docs', // api document URL
      }));

  // install middleware
  swaggerExpress.register(app);

  var port = process.env.PORT || 10010;
  app.listen(port);

  if (swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.paths['/hello']) {
    console.log('try this:\ncurl http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/hello?name=Scott');
  }
});
```

when i run this command:

> node app.js

**console error**

> Error initializing middleware
>   Error: Swagger document(s) failed validation so the server cannot
>
> ...\node_modules\swagger-tools\index.js:72:13
>
> start
>
> swagger-tools\middleware\swagger-ui.js:74
>   throw new TypeError('rlOrSO must be an object');